# how can i get csv in google appsscript?

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, urlfetch

```
function myFunction() {
  var gen_otp_url = 'http://data.krx.co.kr/comm/fileDn/GenerateOTP/generate.cmd'

  // #otp payload
  var gen_otp_data  = {'locale' : 'ko_KR',
  'mktId' : 'STK',
  'trdDd' : '20221205',
  'money' : '1',
  'csvxls_isNo' : 'false',
  'name' : 'fileDown',
  'url' : 'dbms/MDC/STAT/standard/MDCSTAT03901'};
  var options = {
      'method' : 'post',
      'contentType': 'application/json',
      'payload' : gen_otp_data};
  var otp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(gen_otp_url, options);
  Logger.log(otp.getContentText())

  var csv_url = 'http://data.krx.co.kr/comm/fileDn/download_csv/download.cmd'
  var gen_csv_data = {'code' : otp };
  var csv_options = {
      'method' : 'post',
      'contentType': 'application/json',
      'muteHttpExceptions': true,
      'payload' : gen_csv_data};
  var csv = UrlFetchApp.fetch(csv_url, csv_options);

  Logger.log(csv.getContentText());

}
```

I want to load the csv log with this..

```
Logger.log(csv.getContentText());
```

When I did the same code on Python, it was a byte code, so I decoded it, but it didn't work on appsscript...

i tried this. it doesn't  work...

```
function to64(arr) {
  var bytes = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
    bytes.push(arr[i]<128?arr[i]:arr[i]-256);
  return Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(bytes)
} // to64
```

Comment: Can you provide the sample value of `Logger.log(csv.getContentText());`?

Comment: csv.getContentText()  have notthing..

Comment: csv.getAllHeaders()

Comment: {Expires=Tue, 06 Dec 2022 12:22:52 GMT, Connection=keep-alive, Content-Type=application/octet-stream;charset=UTF-8, Cache-Control=max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, content-transfer-encoding=binary, Content-Length=0, mod_time=1670329372000, Set-Cookie=JSESSIONID=UbTHpDMYJ1t2CAipdec4YkTQEYDUus7VeruNFzVThwsEphRgbkz9J64mCaRN2ICP.bWRjX2RvbWFpbi9tZGNvd2FwMi1tZGNhcHAxMQ==; Domain=.krx.co.kr; Path=/; HttpOnly, Date=Tue, 06 Dec 2022 12:22:52 GMT, Content-Disposition=attachment; filename=data_2252_20221206.csv, Pragma=no-cache}

Comment: csv.getHeaders()

Comment: {Date=Tue, 06 Dec 2022 12:22:52 GMT, Content-Type=application/octet-stream;charset=UTF-8, mod_time=1670329372000, Expires=Tue, 06 Dec 2022 12:22:52 GMT, Pragma=no-cache, Cache-Control=max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, Content-Disposition=attachment; filename=data_2252_20221206.csv, Connection=keep-alive, Set-Cookie=JSESSIONID=UbTHpDMYJ1t2CAipdec4YkTQEYDUus7VeruNFzVThwsEphRgbkz9J64mCaRN2ICP.bWRjX2RvbWFpbi9tZGNvd2FwMi1tZGNhcHAxMQ==; Domain=.krx.co.kr; Path=/; HttpOnly, Content-Length=0, content-transfer-encoding=binary}

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `csv.getContentText() have notthing`, in this case, the data is not included. So, first, I think that it is required to retrieve the data. For example, can you provide the detailed specification of the API you want to use?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please add all the relevant details directly into the question body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function myFunction() {
  var gen_otp_url = 'http://data.krx.co.kr/comm/fileDn/GenerateOTP/generate.cmd'

  // #otp payload
  var gen_otp_data  = {'locale' : 'ko_KR',
  'mktId' : 'STK',
  'trdDd' : '20221205',
  'money' : '1',
  'csvxls_isNo' : 'false',
  'name' : 'fileDown',
  'url' : 'dbms/MDC/STAT/standard/MDCSTAT03901'};
  var options = {
      'method' : 'post',
      'payload' : gen_otp_data};
  var otp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(gen_otp_url, options);

  Logger.log(otp.getContentText())

  var csv_url = 'http://data.krx.co.kr/comm/fileDn/download_csv/download.cmd'
  var gen_csv_data = {'code' : otp.getContentText() };
  var csv_options = {
      'method' : 'post',
      'muteHttpExceptions': true,
      'payload' : gen_csv_data};
  var csv = UrlFetchApp.fetch(csv_url, csv_options);

  Logger.log(csv.getContentText("cp949"))
}
```

I removed this, 'contentType': 'application/json',

Answer (score -1):

I want to get this..
AqADUIYgYA1S7YNpohdEFcDGdj9Dk3U4+1LksLL0tDQRtSksuLS7Bnxpl86F7dAOkunw9BBwugQaSjGAcH15eTgGZqZmUYRxtFW2OJYnOsQtBgM+EFJCxYg3zco1gIgRZqIo4cIzoURnTI8+MmkJ4v/rk8yudrOQ53ef0cNipdpCT2QuimcLoNhc1Lfcxcp2zXt/wiFT3lY4zZLV84P+nFYo9mrWvGCVTr7yVbjg2wtc9glyj0xDQ2lZrfrchZWN

but i get this.. from Logger.log(otp.getContentText())

AqADUIYgYA1S7YNpohdEFUP2/gB8rhRtkSnlEoAJIio=

Logger.log(Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(otp.getContent()))
QXFBRFVJWWdZQTFTN1lOcG9oZEVGUlk5SHIzUDJBUVJKMDYvMnNmQTEvOD0=

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).